# How do I add a service broker to Bluemix / Cloud Foundry?

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a private service broker for Cloud Foundry / Bluemix as [found, e.g., here on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cloud%20foundry%20service%20broker). When I try to register the broker using
`cf create-service-broker brokername username password URI2Broker`
I get the following error:

> Creating service broker brokername as BluemixUser...
>        FAILED
>            Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action

How can I use a private service broker with Bluemix or Cloud Foundry even if I am not an administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry has two types of private brokers, [standard private brokers and space-scoped private brokers](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/managing-service-brokers.html). The latter can be registered even without administrator privileges and are only visible in the space they are registered in ("space-scoped"). You can use the following command:

`cf create-service-broker brokername username password URI2Broker --space-scoped`

There are some rules to follow, e.g., several identifiers need to be unique within the Cloud Foundry instance. You can find more information in this [tutorial on registering private brokers](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Bluemix-ServiceBroker) which has links to samples and more documentation.